# Can't use pip to install pandas with problems in upgrading numpy, six, and python-dateutil

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, numpy, pip, python-dateutil

I can't use `pip` to install `pandas` with problems in upgrading numpy and `pytho-dateutil`. After a few tries, I believe the problem lies in `pip` default installation path.
How can I solve this issue and install `pandas` successfully?

Python 2.7 was already installed in my Mac, when I wanted to `import pandas`, I noticed an error message to suggest to upgrade `python-dateuntil` to 2.5.0.

```py
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 438, in <module>
    raise ImportError('dateutil 2.5.0 is the minimum required version')
ImportError: dateutil 2.5.0 is the minimum required version
```

So I used pip to upgrade `python-dateutil` but failed with some tries:

1. I upgraded dateutil but found the problems in upgrading `six` and `numpy`.

```sh
$ pip install --upgrade python-dateutil
Collecting python-dateutil
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: pandas 0.24.2 has requirement numpy>=1.12.0, but you'll have numpy 1.8.0rc1 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: six, python-dateutil
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'six'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

2. So I tried to upgrade `six` and `numpy` first. However, I had a PATH issue when installing numpy.

```sh
$ pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed numpy --user
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8f/0b/1a2c21bb69138337dc079841aa4a45e5b2fc7a4260c0907f5254fb08f02e/numpy-1.16.4-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
ERROR: pandas 0.24.2 has requirement python-dateutil>=2.5.0, but you'll have python-dateutil 1.5 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: numpy
  WARNING: The scripts f2py, f2py2 and f2py2.7 are installed in '/Users/myname/Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed numpy-1.16.4
```

```sh
$ pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed six --user
Collecting six
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six
Successfully installed six-1.12.0
```

3. check with `pip` if `numpy` and `six` were updated. It seems the version of `six` and `numpy` are still the old version.

```sh
$ pip show numpy
Name: numpy
Version: 1.8.0rc1
Summary: NumPy: array processing for numbers, strings, records, and objects.
Home-page: http://www.numpy.org
Author: NumPy Developers
Author-email: numpy-discussion@scipy.org
License: BSD
Location: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Requires: 
Required-by: pypanda, matplotlib, pandas
```

```sh
$ pip show six
Name: six
Version: 1.4.1
Summary: Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
Home-page: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/
Author: Benjamin Peterson
Author-email: benjamin@python.org
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Requires: 
Required-by: singledispatch
```

4. I tried to ignore `six` and `numpy` to install `pandas`. I found `pandas` can be installed but located in another directory different with `numpy` and `six`.

```sh
$ pip install pandas --ignore-installed numpy six --user

Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/52/ff/912fe03a623a70bcf297d466013a0b4f4c68c3b60f86bf226682d061fc09/pandas-0.24.2-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8f/0b/1a2c21bb69138337dc079841aa4a45e5b2fc7a4260c0907f5254fb08f02e/numpy-1.16.4-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Collecting six
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz>=2011k (from pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/73/fe30c2daaaa0713420d0382b16fbb761409f532c56bdcc514bf7b6262bb6/pytz-2019.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.5.0 (from pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy, pytz, six, python-dateutil, pandas
  WARNING: The scripts f2py, f2py2 and f2py2.7 are installed in '/Users/myname/Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed numpy-1.16.4 pandas-0.24.2 python-dateutil-2.8.0 pytz-2019.1 six-1.12.0
```

```sh
$ pip show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 0.24.2
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
Home-page: http://pandas.pydata.org
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requires: numpy, pytz, python-dateutil
Required-by: pypanda
```

Given the error messages above, even though I can't fully understand the relation of these two directories -- `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`and`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python`, which one is supposed to be the right python library installation directory? I was thinking my problem lies in `pip` default installation location, but I don't how to solve this problem. 
I expect to solve this problem without any python alternations e.g. python3 or python virtual environment.

Thanks in advance!